# Keeping track of play time with multiple variables and while loops

Tags: c++, time, while-loop, sfml

I want to add a mode to my game where the time the player needs to complete the game is tracked.

My current solution is this: I have four variables (for various reasons) that keep track of the time:

```
int timerMilliseconds_= 0;
int timerSeconds_ = 0;
int timerMinutes_ = 0;
int timerHours_ = 0;
```

Whenever I update my game, I increase `timerMilliseconds_` by the current delta time and update the values. It looks like this:

```
timerMilliseconds_ += dt.asMilliseconds();

if (timerMilliseconds_ >= 1000) {

  while (timerMilliseconds_ >= 1000) {
    timerMilliseconds_ -= 1000;
    timerSeconds_++;
  }

  while (timerSeconds_ >= 60) {
    timerSeconds_ -= 60;
    timerMinutes_++;
  }

  while (timerMinutes_ >= 60) {
    timerMinutes_ -= 60;
    timerHours_++;
  }

}
```

This code seems to be working but it looks kind of... weird... to me.

Do these while loops make sense? Am I overengineering this?

I know this is almost codereview worthy but I figured I could get a better answer here! Thank you!

Comment: It seems pretty strange to me to keep four separate variables for tracking play time. I'd rather make a tiny wrapper around unsigned int for this with 1 member and time conversion functions for minutes/seconds/hours :) Unless you're using all the four variables in every frame

Comment: Adding to BlackCat's comment, even if you are using all four time units in every frame, you could convert with integer division and modulo each time - no different than counting for each unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counting repeated subtractions is equivalent to (integer) division; what remains is the remainder.
So you can use arithmetic:

```
timerSeconds = timerMilliseconds / 1000;
timerMilliseconds = timerMilliseconds % 1000;
timerMinutes = timerSeconds / 60;
timerSeconds = timerSeconds % 60;
timerHours = timerMinutes / 60;
timerMinutes = timerMinutes % 60;
```